# controlling mouse while pc user account is locked

Tags: vb.net, mouse

I have small application that move mouse to specific location in screen and do click. can I modify it so it still working even computer user account is locked?

what i want to do is move mouse cursor toward position in running windows store game and do click many times.

as I know when computer user account is locked MS Windows will control mouse and my application loose mouse control.

I am using vb.net and MS Windows 10.

I do appreciate your help.

Comment: to clarify, do you want to move it and click on the lock screen or on the user's desktop that is still logged in?

Comment: thanks for reply, I want to click on windows store game. but when pc is locked all actions(move,click) applied on lock screen.

Comment: Mouse clicks are directed to the foreground Window. You can use UI Automation: [System.Windows.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation) to target a non-foreground application. The [InvokePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern) Pattern is used to trigger a click event on a control that supports that pattern.

Comment: does it work even PC locked? my clicks will be inside windows store not inside my application.thanks

Comment: hi again, I need to get the answer (yes or no) please. then I will continue programming.

Comment: You may have to experiment to find out